# Add multiple source test directories for tests

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with the following directory structure:

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
src/test/java
src/test/resources
```

I want to add a new folder, `integrationTest`:

```
src/integrationTest/java
src/integrationTest/resources
```

Where I want to keep integration tests totally separate from unit tests. How should I go about adding this? In the build.gradle, I'm not sure how to specify a new task that'd pick this folder build it and run the tests separately.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gradle has a concept of `source sets` which is exactly what you need here. You have a detailed documentation about that in the *Java Plugin* documenation here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_source_sets

You can define a new source set "integrationTest" in your `build.gradle`

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir file('src/integration-test/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/integration-test/resources')
    }
}
```

This will automatically create new *configurations* `integrationTestCompile` and `integrationTestRuntime`, that you can use to define an new *Task* `integrationTests`:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

For reference : a working full example can be found here : https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/

Comment: How do I create a task that runs these tests only?

Comment: I updated my answer. You should also read the full article I mentioned, which provides the full steps  (configure the dependency between these two configurations which should extends from "testCompile" and "testRuntim", and include the "integrationTest" task in the "check" lifecycle task

Comment: it goes better with
```groovy
compileClasspath += sourceSets.test.compileClasspath
runtimeClasspath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
```
Gradle takes all the dependencies from the test also

Comment: JFI - for those who want main/test dependencies also be available for integrationTests, don't forget to update 'configurations' and add 'extendsFrom' calls as per https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Answer (score 8):

Please add the newly created source folder also to source sets in **build.gradle** as below:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src']
    }
  }

  test {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['test']
    }
  }
  integrationTest {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['integrationTest']
    }
  }
}
```

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

The new feature of declarative tests suites introduced in Gradle 7.3 (released November 2021) can easily solve this need without all the low level plumbing details. To use it, add the `jvm-test-suite` plugin to your build script plugins.

```
testing {
  suites {
    val integrationTest by registering(JvmTestSuite::class) {
      dependencies {
        implementation(project())
      }

      targets {
        all {
          testTask.configure {
            shouldRunAfter(test)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

tasks.named("check") {
  dependsOn(testing.suites.named("integrationTest"))
}
```

You can find more information about this feature here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html.